# Using Radio Button in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, radio-button

I have a **RadioButton** inside a **gridview** and I use a image button to change to next page and for **RadioButton** value in the current page with an hidden field.

But when i try to retrieve the selected value in  RadioButton (hidden field), it returns empty string.

Can anyone please help me?

My code below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("RadioButton1");

        if (rb.Checked)
        {
            HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            Response.Write(rb.Text.ToString() + "<br />" + hf.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("empty<br />");
        }
    }
}

<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" onclick="RadioCheck(this);" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Area").ToString()%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" ImageUrl="/Images/button.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error on 9th line

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
   {
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("RadioButton1");

    if (rb.Checked)
    {
        HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("HiddenField1");
        Response.Write(rb.Text.ToString() + "<br />" + hf.Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("empty<br />");
    }
}
}
```